# How do I check whether an item is a member of a list in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have implemented this function. It is supposed to check the input that we have given to it, and if it is found in the list, a "True" will be shown on the screen. However, it just works for the numbers and if I give it a character I receive an error.

```
(defun element (x lst)
  (dolist (item lst) 
    (if (= item x) (return t))))
```

How can I modify it so that it can also look for any characters given to it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, use #'eq instead of #'=, thus the 3rd line becomes: `(if (eq item x) ...`

Alternatively, you could use the built-in [#'intersection](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_isec_.htm) to check if any of the given items are in the list, thus: `(if (not (eq (intersection lst '(x)) nil)))`

Comment: `eql` is usually a better equality predicate than `eq` (try, for example, `(list (= (/ 1 2) (/ 2 4)) (eq (/ 1 2) (/ 2 4)) (eql (/ 1 2) (/ 2 4)))` and see if the result surprises you).

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, [the `=` function](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq_sle.htm) only works with numbers.

If you try basing your function on [`find`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_find_.htm) instead, you'll likely find that its default use of [the `eql` function](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_eql.htm) as its *test* provides the behavior you seek:

```
(defun element (needle haystack)
  (not (null (find needle haystack))))
```

As alternates to `find`, you should also study its siblings [`member`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mem_m.htm) and [`position`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_pos_p.htm#position). In your case, since you only want to distinguish between the item having been found or not, you should choose the function that does the least work. My guess is that `position` loses here, and that `member` and `find` are equivalent; `member` returns the list from which it extracted the `car`, whereas `find` returns the `car`. In both functions, it's necessary to extract the `car`.

Comment: It now works perfectly by just replacing the "eq" with the "=" sign.
Thanks alot for your kind help.

Comment: I take it you meant the converse, replacing "=" with "eq." Make sure you understand the difference between `eq`, `eql`, `equal`, `equalp`, and kin.

Answer (score 1):

There are several comparison operators.  The general ones are `eq`, `eql`, `equal` and `equalp`.  Look them up in the hyperspec.

For objects of specific types, there are often specialized comparators, e.g. `string=` and `char=`.

Finally, for list operations, there are functions like `member`, which can free you from writing loops by hand.  They take an optional `test` parameter, through which you can pass the comparison function.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly. But just one question what is the difference between "eq" functionality of and "equalp" functionality??